# Using Regex to pull from table results

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape table from a series of similar websites. Here's one of the pages that's giving me trouble:

Fail URL: https://www.nysenate.gov/legislation/bills/2011/s79

Succeed URL: https://www.nysenate.gov/legislation/bills/2013/s97

Using BeautifulSoup, the scraper pulls down the table and turns all of the td into a list. Then using regex, I run an if statement to see if it has info I'm looking for.

If it does, then it should get stuffed into a dataframe. Except it doesn't for some webpages.
I've compared the response text between pages this works for and doesn't.

I have a print statement spit out the entire list and tested my regexs on those (they work). But I absolutely cannot figure out why the scraper repeatedly fails to pulls the same information from the same pages and continues on others. Here's the relevant code:

```
check_list = [item.text.strip() for item in tablebody.select("td")]

tablebody=soup.select_one(".table.c-bill--actions-table > tbody")

check_list = [item.text.strip() for item in tablebody.select("td")]

signed_regex = re.compile('(?i)signed')

signed_index = "signed"

        try:       
            if any(signed_regex.match(thing) for thing in check_list):
                transfer_list.append("true")
                transfer_list.append(check_list[0])

            elif signed_index in check_list:
                i = check_list.index(signed_index)
                transfer_list.append("true")
                transfer_list.append(check_list[0])
          
            else:
                transfer_list.append("false")
                transfer_list.append("no date")

        except Exception as e:
            transfer_list.append(e)
```

Comment: Can you also include an url that does work?

Comment: You do not need a regex. `if any(signed_regex.match(thing) for thing in check_list)` can be replaced with `if any(thing.lower()=='signed' for thing in check_list)`, `elif` block is doing the same thing, you can remove it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it's still not working. It's still failing on the "fail" URL. This is what I have:

`if any(thing.lower()=='signed' for thing in check_list):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can use :contains to target the td with that text and then use .parent.td to move to the td before to get the date

```
import requests, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

links = ['https://www.nysenate.gov/legislation/bills/2013/s97', 'https://www.nysenate.gov/legislation/bills/2011/s79']
transfer_list = []

with requests.Session() as s:
    for link in links:
        r = s.get(link)
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
        target = soup.select_one('.cbill--actions-table--row td:contains("signed")')
        if target:
            transfer_list.append("true")
            transfer_list.append(target.parent.td.text)
        else:
            transfer_list.append("false")
            transfer_list.append("no date")
```

Comment: Thanks QHarr. This is working great. Is it also possible to go the other way? Is there a `child` method? One scenario (that I didn't list) I need to go the opposite direction instead of `parent`

Comment: could you explain using an example from the shared urls?

Comment: I amended my question. What I'm looking for now is underneath the `--EDIT--` part.

Comment: Done. I asked a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66987233/using-beautiful-soup-to-pull-dates-from-table