# Using Beautiful Soup to pull dates from table

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm looking to do something with bills that have been delivered to the governor - collecting dates for when they were delivered and the date of the last legislative action before they were sent.

I'm doing this for a whole series of similar URLs. Problem is, my code (below) works for some URLs and not others. I'm writing this to a pandas dataframe and then to csv file. When the code fails, it writes the `else` block when either `if` of `elif` should've been triggered.

Here's a fail URL: https://www.nysenate.gov/legislation/bills/2011/s663
And a succeed URL: https://www.nysenate.gov/legislation/bills/2011/s333

Take the first URL for example. Underneath the "view actions" dropdown, it says it was delivered to the governor on Jul 29, 2011. Prior to that, it was returned to assembly on Jun 20, 2011.

Using "delivered to governor" location as td in the table, I'd like to collect both dates using Bs4.

Here's what I have in my code:

```py
check_list = [item.text.strip() for item in tablebody.select("td")]

dtg = "delivered to governor"
dtg_regex = re.compile(
    '/.*(\S\S\S\S\S\S\S\S\S\s\S\S\s\S\S\S\S\S\S\S\S).*'
)
        
if dtg in check_list:

    i = check_list.index(dtg)
    transfer_list.append(check_list[i+1]) ## last legislative action date (not counting dtg)
    transfer_list.append(check_list[i-1]) ## dtg date
            
elif any(dtg_regex.match(dtg_check_list) for dtg_check_list in check_list):
    transfer_list.append(check_list[4])
    transfer_list.append(check_list[2])
            
else:
    transfer_list.append("no floor vote")
    transfer_list.append("not delivered to governor")
```

Comment: So you want "If `Delivered To Governor` exists then get the date and the most recent `return to assembly/senate` date before it."?

Comment: Mostly. I think the best way to describe what I'm looking for is "If `Delivered To Governor` exists, then snag dates on either side of it. The date it was delivered (the ancestor?) and the last legislative action (which is usually some return to `assembly/senate` - but not always.

Comment: I see, please see my answer.

Comment: So you don't care what happened prior to `delivered to governor`, just get the date?

Comment: Any luck with my code?

Comment: I keep getting an `invalid syntax` error. I think it might be a  language issue...First it was the `//`, then the `.` in the `lower-case` parens, then it was the double-colon. I'm trying to do this:

`
`transfer_list.append(//text()[contains(lower-case(.), 'delivered to governor')]/ancestor::tr/td[1]/text())`
`transfer_list.append(//text()[contains(lower-case(.), 'delivered to governor')]/ancestor::tr/following-sibling::tr[1]/td/text())`

Comment: You need to properly interpolate the XPath into a Python string. I am not a Python developer but escaping strings should be one of the first things you learned; well before asking this question at least.

Comment: Right...I'm still relatively new to this. I escaped all parts of your code throwing the syntax error and I wrapped the entire thing in quotes (which apparently I need to do when I escape a character).

Now it's appending the xpath as a string instead of using it to get the necessary info. It'ls probably because. Do I need to use a `get` or some similar method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use :has and :contains to target the right first row and find_next to move to next row. You can use last-of-type to get last action in first row select_one to get first in second row. You can use the class of each "column" to move between first and second columns.

Your mileage may vary with other pages.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

links = ['https://www.nysenate.gov/legislation/bills/2011/s663', 'https://www.nysenate.gov/legislation/bills/2011/s333']
transfer_list = []

with requests.Session() as s:
    for link in links:
        r = s.get(link)
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
        target = soup.select_one('.cbill--actions-table--row:has(td:contains("delivered"))')
        
        if target:
            print(target.select_one('.c-bill--actions-table-col1').text)
            # transfer_list.append(target.select_one('.c-bill--actions-table-col1').text)   
            print(target.select_one('.c-bill--action-line-assembly:last-of-type, .c-bill--action-line-senate:last-of-type').text)
            # transfer_list.append(target.select_one('.c-bill--action-line-assembly:last-of-type, .c-bill--action-line-senate:last-of-type').text)
            print(target.find_next('tr').select_one('.c-bill--actions-table-col1').text)
            # append again
            print(target.find_next('tr').select_one('.c-bill--actions-table-col2 span').text)
            # append again
        else:
            transfer_list.append("no floor vote")
            transfer_list.append("not delivered to governor")
```

Answer (score 0):

Make full use of XPath:

---

Get date of "delivered to governor"

```
//text()[contains(lower-case(.), 'delivered to governor')]/ancestor::tr/td[1]/text()
```

S663A - http://xpather.com/bUQ6Gva8

S333 - http://xpather.com/oTNfuH75

---

Get date of "returned to assembly/senate"

```
//text()[contains(lower-case(.), 'delivered to governor')]/ancestor::tr/following-sibling::tr/td//text()[contains(lower-case(.), 'returned to')]/ancestor::tr/td[1]/text()
```

S663A - http://xpather.com/Rnufm2TB

S333 - http://xpather.com/4x9UHn4L

---

Get date of action which precedes "delivered to governor" row regardless of what the action is

```
//text()[contains(lower-case(.), 'delivered to governor')]/ancestor::tr/following-sibling::tr[1]/td/text()
```

S663A - http://xpather.com/AUpWCFIz

S333 - http://xpather.com/u8LOCb0x